# How can I set a database schema in a springboot project?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot

I am developing a flyway project.

I tried setting `schema` using the property

```
spring.datasource.schema=myschema
```

However, this didn't help.

The project just consist of versions `sql` files that need to be executed to build the database schema.

How can I specify the database schema?

I do not want to alter the `search_path` and set it to myschema as the `database` is being used by other applications and they need to connect to the `mainschema`.

Comment: Yes, I only have one username though that we use to connect to our database

Comment: that worked, thanks!

Comment: In the url ->     ?currentSchema=myschema

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Can you please write an answer to this question so that I can give you credit?

Comment: Your solutions worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [documented in the manual](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html#connection-parameters) you can append the current schema to the JDBC URL:

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost/database_name?currentSchema=myschema
```